# Pandas extract percentile range from multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
Group  |  Day  |  Value
A          1        0.12
A          2        ...
A          3
A          4
A          5
A          6
B          3
B          4
B          6
B          7
C          3
C          1001
C          1002
```

`Group` and `Day` being levels in a multiindex. How can I extract data between "ordinal" percentiles of length for each group (so I don't care about the value of the day, I care about days being between 2 percentages of all the days)?

So, let's say I wanted between the 0.5 and 0.9 percentile (inclusively) for each group.

- The length of group A is 6
- The length of group B is 4
- The length of group C is 3

That would mean I would get

- between the 3rd listed day and 5th listed day for A
- between the 2nd listed day and 3rd listed day for B
- the 2nd listed day for C

Some notes about the data:

- all days for each group are in order
- some days are missing
- they don't necessarily start, or end, on a given day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like we can do `cumcount` and `transform`

```
g = df.groupby('Group')
s = g.cumcount()/g['Group'].transform('count')
out = df[s.between(0.5,0.9)]
   Group   Day
3      A     4
4      A     5
5      A     6
8      B     6
9      B     7
12     C  1002
```